# IE 11 doesn't honor image widths when printing

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

It appears that IE 11 doesn't honor image widths when printing. For example, I have an image in my HTML page like so:

```
<img src="https://myserver/handler.ashx?id=12345" width="600">
```

When the page is viewed in IE 11 it looks perfect. The original image is large (maybe 3000px) but it renders and reduces to 600px, just as expected. But when I print that page, the image seems to ignore the `width="600"` and try to render the whole thing, and it pushes content out and looks terrible.

**Note: The `<img>` is inside a `<td>`, in case that makes a difference.**

What can be done? Some kind of CSS? Different attribute on the IMG tag?

Comment: try the print css media : `@media print {img {max-width:100%;/* or whatever you want */} }`

Comment: That didn't seem to have any effect.